# Trying to compare 2 arrays of arrays and creating new arrays if values match in PHP

Tags: php

Here is an example dataset

```
$all_items = array (
  $a1 = array (
      name => "item1",
      description => "item 1",
      item_key => 123
  ),
  $a2 = array (
      name => "item2",
      description => "item 2",
      item_key => 456
  ),
  $a3 = array (
      name => "item3",
      description => "item 3",
      item_key => 789
  )
);

$invoice_items = array (
  $b1 = array (
      item_key => 123,
      desc => "1item"
  ),
  $b2 = array (
      item_key => 456,
      desc => "2item"
  ),
  $b3 = array (
      item_key => 123,
      desc => "3item"
  ),
  $b4 = array (
      item_key => 345,
      desc => "4item"
  ),
  $b5 = array (
      item_key => 123,
      desc => "5item"
  ),
  $b6 = array (
      item_key => 345,
      desc => "6item"
  ),
  $b7 = array (
      item_key => 123,
      desc => "7item"
  )
);
```

So the goal here is wherever there is an invoice item that matches the `item_key` of an item, I want to throw the invoice_item array into a new array. So in this example I think I want an outcome like this

```
Array (
   [0] => Array (
      [0] => Array ( [name] => item1 [description] => item 1 [item_key] => 123 ),
      [1] => Array ( [item_key] => 123 [desc] => 1item ),
      [2] => Array ( [item_key] => 123 [desc] => 3item ),
      [3] => Array ( [item_key] => 123 [desc] => 5item ),
      [4] => Array ( [item_key] => 123 [desc] => 7item )
   )

   [1] => Array (
      [0] => Array ( [name] => item2 [description] => item 2 [item_key] => 456 ),
      [1] => Array ( [item_key] => 456 [desc] => 2item ),
   )

   [2] => Array (
      [0] => Array ( [name] => item3 [description] => item 3 [item_key] => 789 )
   )
)
```

Any advise?

I've tried to just compare the arrays and push the values but then I just end up with one big array and kind of back to where I started. I'm still a little new to php and maybe unfamiliar with some array methods

Comment: Your example datasets are not syntactically correct. Does that bother you? If it does, could you correct it?

Comment: I have a working version of some stuff I'm working on with this and it is correct. Thanks though!

Comment: This is the error I get: https://3v4l.org/Iuk6I And you can see that lukas.j tries to correct it in his answer.

Comment: but name is a key...it doesn't need to be set? Again, I have this as a working example ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

```
$all_items = [
  $a1 = [ 'name' => 'item1', 'description' => 'item 1', 'item_key' => 123 ],
  $a2 = [ 'name' => 'item2', 'description' => 'item 2', 'item_key' => 456 ],
  $a3 = [ 'name' => 'item3', 'description' => 'item 3', 'item_key' => 789 ]
];

$invoice_items = [
  $b1 = [ 'item_key' => 123, 'desc' => '1item' ],
  $b2 = [ 'item_key' => 456, 'desc' => '2item' ],
  $b3 = [ 'item_key' => 123, 'desc' => '3item' ],
  $b4 = [ 'item_key' => 345, 'desc' => '4item' ],
  $b5 = [ 'item_key' => 123, 'desc' => '5item' ],
  $b6 = [ 'item_key' => 345, 'desc' => '6item' ],
  $b7 = [ 'item_key' => 123, 'desc' => '7item' ]
];

$invoices = [];
foreach ($invoice_items as $invoice_item) {
  $invoices[$invoice_item['item_key']][] = $invoice_item;
}

$result = [];
foreach ($all_items as $all_item) {
  $result[] = array_merge([ $all_item ], $invoices[$all_item['item_key']] ?? []);
}
```

The result array has the same structure as yours depicted in your question above.

But you have a contradiction between your result set and your comment '... the invoice_item array into a new array'. Your result array appends the invoice items, hence my code above.

Now this solution would indeed create a new key – here called 'descs' – with the invoice items in an array under this key:

```
$invoices = [];
foreach ($invoice_items as $invoice_item) {
  $invoices[$invoice_item['item_key']][] = $invoice_item;
}

foreach ($all_items as &$all_item) {
  $all_item['descs'] = $invoices[$all_item['item_key']] ?? [];
}
unset($all_item);
```

And because the item_key is redundant in these 'descs' array entries, you could drop them and just create an array of strings:

```
$invoices = [];
foreach ($invoice_items as $invoice_item) {
  $invoices[$invoice_item['item_key']][] = $invoice_item['desc'];
}

foreach ($all_items as &$all_item) {
  $all_item['descs'] = $invoices[$all_item['item_key']] ?? [];
}
unset($all_item);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => item1
            [description] => item 1
            [item_key] => 123
            [descs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1item
                    [1] => 3item
                    [2] => 5item
                    [3] => 7item
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => item2
            [description] => item 2
            [item_key] => 456
            [descs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2item
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => item3
            [description] => item 3
            [item_key] => 789
            [descs] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

---

Please note that both your input arrays have assignments within their construction ($a1 = ..., $a2 = ..., etc.). This does not make to much sense, unless you need these variables later on. If so, it would be more readable to code it this way:

```
$a1 = [ 'name' => 'item1', 'description' => 'item 1', 'item_key' => 123 ],
$a2 = [ 'name' => 'item2', 'description' => 'item 2', 'item_key' => 456 ],
$a3 = [ 'name' => 'item3', 'description' => 'item 3', 'item_key' => 789 ]

$all_items = [ $a1, $a2, $a3 ];
```

Comment: So this is kind of abbreviated data coming from a query I've written and it's coming back to me as an array of arrays but instead of $a1, etc, it looks more like [0] => ,[1] => , etc so just for my own readability as I'm just trying to test proof of concept I changed them to variables. This solution looks pretty close to what I want so I'll have to do some more testing with my much larger data structure. Thanks!